# visual studio 2017 installer keeps asking me to update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to download the windows form application template for c# in visual studio 2017. but when I open the visual studio installer it's asking me to update, and when I finish updating its asking me again and I can never open the actual installer.

[image]

Comment: Better to post this question on msdn forum

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Start your Visual Studio 2017
2. Update it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-visual-studio )
3. Restart the IDE

Then download the application template.

Answer (score 0):

You have to type Visual Studio Installer into Cortana and right click on the application icon to bring up the sub-menu.   From there, click "Run as Administrator" to prevent this infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think that **launching the Visual Studio Installer with Administrator privileges** could work.  From this answer on the Microsoft forums:

> When this happened to me I had to launch Visual Studio Installer through the start menu with administrator privileges. Doing that broke it out of the inifinite update loop. This is just a wild guess on my part but it could be that when launching Visual Studio Installer through Visual Studio it is lacking the necessary permissions to preform the update.
>
> When I did this workaround I was on a different Version Number than you reported so not sure if it will produce the same results as it did for me. Anyways thought I would share in case this helped any.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30271/please-update-visual-studio-installer-endless-loop.html